# C++11 Regular Expression Using Back Reference as Condition

Tags: regex, c++11, character-class

I realize that back references cannot be used in character classes, but I need this functionality. I am wondering if there is an alternative valid regular expression that can be used to accomplish this.

Premises: I am using Visual Studio 2013. It must work within that environment (i.e., std::regex).

As a simplified example, what I wish to perform is a search on a word list that is upper case Roman alphabetic letters only (i.e. A-Z), such as the hypothetical expression:

> "^(.)([A-\1])([\2-Z])$"

This would ideally return a match for 3-letter words, where the 2nd character is lexically less than or equal to the 1st character, and the 3rd character is lexically greater than or equal to the 2nd character. Example matches would include "CAT" and "EEL", but not "COW" nor "PIG".

So, is there a somewhat simple regular expression (excluding the 26×N exponential alternate conditions) that can accomplish this? Or should I just write my own code to do this?

**Addendum:** Not having received an alternate valid regular expression for the simplified case I believe answers my question, in that I will simply need to write my own code for performing such a search.

To understand the real world problem, I'll simply direct you here:

http://joeslater.orgfree.com/ZigWord/tutorial.html

The tutorial will probably be enough to understand the problem, but there are a few puzzles provided which you are certainly welcome to try. They were all hand-generated. I need my program to generate such puzzles using a list of words from which to choose.

The real issue comes when the puzzle sizes become somewhat large, such as a 9×9 or 11×11 grid, along with a large list of words (a few hundred or thousand). The brute force method of trying each word to fit in the unfilled locations as the puzzle gets built is an unacceptable solution – early attempts using such a method ran non-stop for a week before I cancelled it, using a list of 1,300 words for an 11×11 puzzle (no puzzles were generated).

So I was hoping to use regular expressions as the puzzle gets built to filter out the possible words that would fit in the puzzle. At present, I believe that I'll just have to write my own code to perform this search, but if anyone thinks otherwise please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good case for a hybrid approach: use a simple regex to generate candidate matches, and filter them yourself with custom logic.

Comment: I fear this is the case @John. I was just hoping that maybe there was a regex expression that could be used that I was overlooking or unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that anything you do with regular expressions is going to end up more complex (and probably less readable) than a simple expression like:

```
s.length()==3 && s[0] >= s[1] && s[1] <= s[2]
```

...so yes, in this case I think you're better off writing code of your own.

Comment: Admittedly, my example is oversimplified. If this were always the case, I would agree @Jerry. My real world problem is far more complex, and brute-force methods only work with small dimensions. Otherwise the combinatorial mathematics involved mandate a better solution.

Comment: @JoeSlater: In that case you probably need to tell us more about the real problem for us to be able to help devise a solution very well.

Comment: Very well @Jerry. I will amend the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hex codes inside character class.So one approach can be to find `hex code` of `$1` or `\1` and put it inside `character class`.You will have to create the regex on the run.Something like this

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/57

Here `\x43` is `C` is hard coded.But you can find it easily before replacing it.

Pseudo regex can be

`^(.)([A-(hex code of \1)])([(hex code of \2)-Z])$`

```
         ^^                   ^^
```

These are to be replaced with a small code looking up the table and grabbing hex code for `\1`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how using hex codes will help solve my problem; if it's merely to aid in dynamically replacing on the fly, the backslashes already do that. Dynamic and recursive generation of regex expressions would most definitely be required, but I was hoping for a method where such could be avoided.

Comment: @JoeSlater check demo.Hex codes inside character class does work

Comment: I realize that hex codes inside a character class work @vks, and I did look at the demo. [A-\x43] could also be [A-C] – neither specification helps solve my problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your input. I decided to use a hybrid approach… For example, if the beginning hypothetical expression is:

> "^(.)([A-\1])([\2-Z])$"

Such an expression is not a valid regular expression and has to be handled with custom code, but when the second letter is later known to be I, the expression becomes:

> "^([I-Z])([I])([I-Z])$"

which can be used as a valid regular expression to match "PIT" or "SIT".